# In Parse when i use json data as a message my notification is not reached

Tags: android, push-notification

Here is my MainApplication class.

package com.example.incipientinfopc2.pushtestfinal;

```
    import android.app.Application;

    import com.parse.Parse;
    import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
```

public class MainApplication extends Application {

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Setup Parse
    Parse.initialize(this, "app id", "client id");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `JSON` push , you have to create a receiver   here is  an example I've used it in my project github

[CustomReceiver](https://github.com/tamtom/BAUStudents/blob/master/app/src/main/java/reciver/CustomReciver.java)

and don't forget to declare the receiver in the `AndroidManifest.xml`  file,

hope that will work with you

Comment: yes is did it, nut the problem is same, the notification is not come.

Comment: and also change in Manifest file.

Comment: did you create your own notification ? can you show me your custom receiver?

Comment: tell me your email id i will mail you my class.